# fortran read repeated pattern

Tags: io, formatting, fortran

I have a file looking something like this:

> (    1) 0.9988472 (    5)-0.0455316 (    9)-0.0152022 (
>
> (    2) 0.0000060 (    3) 0.0000060 (    6)-0.0000036 (
>
> (    4)-0.0000036 (

I need to read the integer numbers in brackets and the floats into vectors.
I know in advance how many instances I will read.

If I had a file looking like this

> 1   5   9
>
> 2   3   6
>
> 4

I would do the following:

```
read(unitIn, fmt='(3(I3))') (dummyInt(i), i=1,N)
```

but I cannot figure out how do read in 3 instances of two arrays per line.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is actually straight forward...

```
read(10, iostat=st, fmt='(7(A, A, I5, A, f10.7))')&
    ((dummyC, dummyC, dummyI, dummyC, determinantPrefactors(i)), i=1,numDets)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `I1`?  In any case add the declarations and accept the answer after a bit.  (Then go smack whoever wrote the file!)